# Simple AWS Route53 Health Check that checks db availability in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-route53, aws-cdk, health-check

I'm trying to set up a simple route53 health check that checks if the database is available using python and AWS CDK, but have not been able to find any examples of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the `CfnHealthCheck` construct.  The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.CfnHealthCheck.html) have a complete example.